# Alignment of variable names within regression model within tabular environment

Tags: tables, horizontal-alignment, dcolumn

I have trouble correctly centering the names of each variable to match the coefficients in the following table:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{scrextend}
\usepackage{lastpage}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{array, booktabs, caption}
\usepackage{footnote}
\usepackage{lettrine}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{makecell}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tocloft} 
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{nameref}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{pdflscape}  
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{makecell}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{afterpage}
\usepackage{arydshln}
\usepackage{multirow, makecell}
\usepackage{dcolumn}
   \newcolumntype{d}[1]{D{.}{.}{#1}}   


\begin{document}

\begin{table}[htbp]\centering\scriptsize
\def\sym#1{\ifmmode^{#1}\else\(^{#1}\)\fi}
\caption{ESS regression - Government's responsibility on a scale from 1-10}
\begin{tabular}{l*{7}{d{0}}}
\toprule
                &\shortstack{Job \\ for \\ everyone}
                &\shortstack{Health care \\ for the \\ sick}
                &\shortstack{Standard of \\ living for \\ the old}
                &\shortstack{Standard of \\ living for \\ the unemployed}
                &\shortstack{Child care \\ service for \\ working parents}
                &\shortstack{Paid leave \\ to care for \\ sick family}
                &\shortstack{Index}\\
\midrule
Age             &     0.00         &     0.00\sym{***}&     0.00\sym{***}&     0.00\sym{***}&    -0.00         &     0.00\sym{***}&     0.00\sym{***}\\
Gender          &     0.21\sym{***}&     0.06\sym{**} &     0.11\sym{***}&     0.10\sym{***}&     0.19\sym{***}&     0.21\sym{***}&     0.07\sym{***}\\
Education       &    -0.10\sym{***}&    -0.01\sym{*}  &    -0.04\sym{***}&    -0.03\sym{***}&    -0.02\sym{*}  &    -0.05\sym{***}&    -0.02\sym{***}\\
Household Income&    -0.11\sym{***}&    -0.01\sym{***}&    -0.03\sym{***}&    -0.07\sym{***}&    -0.03\sym{***}&    -0.04\sym{***}&    -0.02\sym{***}\\
Denmark         &     0.00         &     0.00         &     0.00         &     0.00         &     0.00         &     0.00         &     0.00         \\
Switzerland     &    -0.63\sym{***}&    -1.24\sym{***}&    -1.06\sym{***}&    -0.35\sym{***}&    -1.59\sym{***}&    -2.08\sym{***}&    -0.57\sym{***}\\
Czech Republic  &     0.45\sym{***}&    -0.57\sym{***}&    -0.23\sym{**} &    -0.38\sym{***}&    -0.77\sym{***}&    -0.83\sym{***}&    -0.20\sym{***}\\
Germany         &     0.57\sym{***}&    -0.54\sym{***}&    -0.85\sym{***}&    -0.31\sym{***}&    -0.26\sym{***}&    -0.92\sym{***}&    -0.22\sym{***}\\
Belgium         &     0.94\sym{***}&    -0.83\sym{***}&    -0.38\sym{***}&    -0.45\sym{***}&    -0.76\sym{***}&    -0.82\sym{***}&    -0.22\sym{***}\\
Estonia         &     1.24\sym{***}&    -0.19\sym{**} &     0.40\sym{***}&     0.70\sym{***}&     0.18\sym{*}  &    -0.10         &     0.15\sym{***}\\
Spain           &     2.00\sym{***}&     0.09         &     0.46\sym{***}&     1.03\sym{***}&     0.22\sym{**} &    -0.11         &     0.25\sym{***}\\
Finland         &     0.92\sym{***}&    -0.14\sym{*}  &    -0.03         &     0.76\sym{***}&     0.06         &    -0.88\sym{***}&     0.03         \\
France          &     0.55\sym{***}&    -0.79\sym{***}&    -0.33\sym{***}&    -0.42\sym{***}&    -0.89\sym{***}&    -0.94\sym{***}&    -0.25\sym{***}\\
Britain         &     0.17         &    -0.12         &     0.09         &    -0.74\sym{***}&    -1.09\sym{***}&    -1.11\sym{***}&    -0.22\sym{***}\\
Greece          &     2.19\sym{***}&     0.22\sym{**} &     0.38\sym{***}&     1.66\sym{***}&     0.73\sym{***}&    -0.35\sym{***}&     0.34\sym{***}\\
Croatia         &     2.34\sym{***}&    -0.03         &     0.46\sym{***}&     1.04\sym{***}&    -0.35\sym{***}&    -0.20\sym{*}  &     0.21\sym{***}\\
Hungary         &     2.68\sym{***}&     0.21\sym{**} &     0.44\sym{***}&     0.41\sym{***}&     0.36\sym{***}&     0.13         &     0.30\sym{***}\\
Ireland         &     0.31\sym{**} &    -0.28\sym{***}&     0.02         &     0.02         &    -1.26\sym{***}&    -1.33\sym{***}&    -0.21\sym{***}\\
Italy           &     1.95\sym{***}&     0.16\sym{*}  &     0.47\sym{***}&     0.82\sym{***}&     0.26\sym{**} &    -0.35\sym{***}&     0.23\sym{***}\\
Latvia          &     2.77\sym{***}&     0.35\sym{***}&     0.89\sym{***}&     1.73\sym{***}&     0.62\sym{***}&     0.28\sym{***}&     0.48\sym{***}\\
Netherlands     &    -0.04         &    -0.57\sym{***}&    -0.59\sym{***}&    -0.25\sym{**} &    -1.75\sym{***}&    -1.46\sym{***}&    -0.38\sym{***}\\
Norway          &     0.74\sym{***}&     0.11         &     0.38\sym{***}&     0.83\sym{***}&    -0.06         &     0.04         &     0.14\sym{***}\\
Poland          &     1.84\sym{***}&     0.07         &     0.38\sym{***}&    -0.21\sym{*}  &    -0.75\sym{***}&    -0.39\sym{***}&     0.07\sym{**} \\
Portugal        &     1.44\sym{***}&    -0.15         &     0.41\sym{***}&     0.44\sym{***}&     0.14         &    -0.05         &     0.15\sym{***}\\
Romania         &     1.95\sym{***}&    -0.85\sym{***}&    -0.08         &     1.33\sym{***}&    -0.21\sym{*}  &    -0.67\sym{***}&     0.05         \\
Russia          &     2.49\sym{***}&     0.26\sym{***}&     0.92\sym{***}&     0.48\sym{***}&     0.14         &     0.16\sym{*}  &     0.33\sym{***}\\
Sweden          &     0.32\sym{**} &    -0.22\sym{***}&     0.05         &     0.77\sym{***}&    -0.16         &    -0.38\sym{***}&     0.02         \\
Slovenia        &     1.39\sym{***}&    -0.20\sym{**} &     0.03         &     0.08         &     0.08         &    -0.20\sym{*}  &     0.06\sym{*}  \\
Turkey          &     1.49\sym{***}&    -0.65\sym{***}&    -0.22\sym{**} &     1.14\sym{***}&    -0.63\sym{***}&    -0.17\sym{*}  &     0.02         \\
Ukraine         &     3.24\sym{***}&     0.34\sym{***}&     0.91\sym{***}&     1.40\sym{***}&     0.19         &     0.22\sym{*}  &     0.46\sym{***}\\
\bottomrule
\multicolumn{8}{l}{\footnotesize \sym{*} \(p<0.05\), \sym{**} \(p<0.01\), \sym{***} \(p<0.001\)}\\
\end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

I have used the dcolumn package to try an align the point estimates along the decimal point, and I can't figure out how to correctly center the names of the variables above the coefficients.

Any help would be hugely appreciated.

Thank you!

Comment: use `\multicolumn{1}{c}{\shortstack....` so they are in `c` entries not `d` ones

Comment: Hello David, thank you very much for a swift reply! I have tried adding your suggestion to my code, but there is no change at all to the position of the variable names. Is it correctly understood that i should input your code exactly after "&"? So that the following code: &\shortstack{Job... becomes &\multicolumn{1}{c}{\shortstack{Job...  ?

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of manually inserting line breaks in the header cells, I suggest you use an `tabularx` environment and let LaTeX perform the chore of finding line break points. It turns out that it's not necessary to invoke `\scriptsize` -- `\small` works just fine.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{scrextend}
\usepackage{booktabs, caption, tabularx, ragged2e, geometry}
\captionsetup{skip=0.333\baselineskip}
\newcolumntype{C}{>{\Centering\arraybackslash}X}
\newcommand\mC[1]{\multicolumn{1}{C}{#1}}

\usepackage{dcolumn}
\newcolumntype{d}[1]{D{.}{.}{#1}}  

\def\sym#1{\ifmmode^{#1}\else\(^{#1}\)\fi}
\begin{document}

\begin{table}[htbp]
\small
\setlength\tabcolsep{3pt}
\caption{ESS regression -- Government's responsibility on a scale from 1 to 10}
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{@{} l *{7}{d{2.5}} @{}}
\toprule
&\mC{Job for everyone}
&\mC{Health care for the sick}
&\mC{Standard of living for the old}
&\mC{Standard of living for the unemployed}
&\mC{Child care service for working parents}
&\mC{Paid leave to care for sick family}
&\mC{Index}\\
\midrule
Age             &  0.00         &  0.00\sym{***}&  0.00\sym{***}&  0.00\sym{***}& -0.00         &  0.00\sym{***}&  0.00\sym{***}\\
Gender          &  0.21\sym{***}&  0.06\sym{**} &  0.11\sym{***}&  0.10\sym{***}&  0.19\sym{***}&  0.21\sym{***}&  0.07\sym{***}\\
Education       & -0.10\sym{***}& -0.01\sym{*}  & -0.04\sym{***}& -0.03\sym{***}& -0.02\sym{*}  & -0.05\sym{***}& -0.02\sym{***}\\
Household Income& -0.11\sym{***}& -0.01\sym{***}& -0.03\sym{***}& -0.07\sym{***}& -0.03\sym{***}& -0.04\sym{***}& -0.02\sym{***}\\
\addlinespace
Denmark         &  0.00         &  0.00         &  0.00         &  0.00         &  0.00         &  0.00         &  0.00         \\
Switzerland     & -0.63\sym{***}& -1.24\sym{***}& -1.06\sym{***}& -0.35\sym{***}& -1.59\sym{***}& -2.08\sym{***}& -0.57\sym{***}\\
Czech Republic  &  0.45\sym{***}& -0.57\sym{***}& -0.23\sym{**} & -0.38\sym{***}& -0.77\sym{***}& -0.83\sym{***}& -0.20\sym{***}\\
Germany         &  0.57\sym{***}& -0.54\sym{***}& -0.85\sym{***}& -0.31\sym{***}& -0.26\sym{***}& -0.92\sym{***}& -0.22\sym{***}\\
Belgium         &  0.94\sym{***}& -0.83\sym{***}& -0.38\sym{***}& -0.45\sym{***}& -0.76\sym{***}& -0.82\sym{***}& -0.22\sym{***}\\
\addlinespace
Estonia         &  1.24\sym{***}& -0.19\sym{**} &  0.40\sym{***}&  0.70\sym{***}&  0.18\sym{*}  & -0.10         &  0.15\sym{***}\\
Spain           &  2.00\sym{***}&  0.09         &  0.46\sym{***}&  1.03\sym{***}&  0.22\sym{**} & -0.11         &  0.25\sym{***}\\
Finland         &  0.92\sym{***}& -0.14\sym{*}  & -0.03         &  0.76\sym{***}&  0.06         & -0.88\sym{***}&  0.03         \\
France          &  0.55\sym{***}& -0.79\sym{***}& -0.33\sym{***}& -0.42\sym{***}& -0.89\sym{***}& -0.94\sym{***}& -0.25\sym{***}\\
Britain         &  0.17         & -0.12         &  0.09         & -0.74\sym{***}& -1.09\sym{***}& -1.11\sym{***}& -0.22\sym{***}\\
\addlinespace
Greece          &  2.19\sym{***}&  0.22\sym{**} &  0.38\sym{***}&  1.66\sym{***}&  0.73\sym{***}& -0.35\sym{***}&  0.34\sym{***}\\
Croatia         &  2.34\sym{***}& -0.03         &  0.46\sym{***}&  1.04\sym{***}& -0.35\sym{***}& -0.20\sym{*}  &  0.21\sym{***}\\
Hungary         &  2.68\sym{***}&  0.21\sym{**} &  0.44\sym{***}&  0.41\sym{***}&  0.36\sym{***}&  0.13         &  0.30\sym{***}\\
Ireland         &  0.31\sym{**} & -0.28\sym{***}&  0.02         &  0.02         & -1.26\sym{***}& -1.33\sym{***}& -0.21\sym{***}\\
Italy           &  1.95\sym{***}&  0.16\sym{*}  &  0.47\sym{***}&  0.82\sym{***}&  0.26\sym{**} & -0.35\sym{***}&  0.23\sym{***}\\
\addlinespace
Latvia          &  2.77\sym{***}&  0.35\sym{***}&  0.89\sym{***}&  1.73\sym{***}&  0.62\sym{***}&  0.28\sym{***}&  0.48\sym{***}\\
Netherlands     & -0.04         & -0.57\sym{***}& -0.59\sym{***}& -0.25\sym{**} & -1.75\sym{***}& -1.46\sym{***}& -0.38\sym{***}\\
Norway          &  0.74\sym{***}&  0.11         &  0.38\sym{***}&  0.83\sym{***}& -0.06         &  0.04         &  0.14\sym{***}\\
Poland          &  1.84\sym{***}&  0.07         &  0.38\sym{***}& -0.21\sym{*}  & -0.75\sym{***}& -0.39\sym{***}&  0.07\sym{**} \\
Portugal        &  1.44\sym{***}& -0.15         &  0.41\sym{***}&  0.44\sym{***}&  0.14         & -0.05         &  0.15\sym{***}\\
\addlinespace
Romania         &  1.95\sym{***}& -0.85\sym{***}& -0.08         &  1.33\sym{***}& -0.21\sym{*}  & -0.67\sym{***}&  0.05         \\
Russia          &  2.49\sym{***}&  0.26\sym{***}&  0.92\sym{***}&  0.48\sym{***}&  0.14         &  0.16\sym{*}  &  0.33\sym{***}\\
Sweden          &  0.32\sym{**} & -0.22\sym{***}&  0.05         &  0.77\sym{***}& -0.16         & -0.38\sym{***}&  0.02         \\
Slovenia        &  1.39\sym{***}& -0.20\sym{**} &  0.03         &  0.08         &  0.08         & -0.20\sym{*}  &  0.06\sym{*}  \\
Turkey          &  1.49\sym{***}& -0.65\sym{***}& -0.22\sym{**} &  1.14\sym{***}& -0.63\sym{***}& -0.17\sym{*}  &  0.02         \\
Ukraine         &  3.24\sym{***}&  0.34\sym{***}&  0.91\sym{***}&  1.40\sym{***}&  0.19         &  0.22\sym{*}  &  0.46\sym{***}\\
\bottomrule\addlinespace
\multicolumn{8}{@{}l}{\footnotesize \(\sym{*}\ p<0.05\), \(\sym{**}\ p<0.01\), \(\sym{***}\ p<0.001\)}\\
\end{tabularx}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Mico, this is absolutely wonderful - thank you so much for your reply, it's going straight into my work. How I love these fora.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `siunitx`; also the `tabular*` environment will take care of filling the spaces.

I also suggest a second version of the table that might even allow for normal size instead of `\scriptsize`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{array, booktabs, caption, siunitx}
\usepackage{dcolumn}

\newcolumntype{d}[1]{D{.}{.}{#1}}

\NewDocumentCommand{\splitcell}{m}{\begin{tabular}[t]{@{}c@{}}#1\end{tabular}}


\begin{document}

\begin{table}[htbp]\centering\scriptsize
\newcommand{\sym}[1]{\ensuremath{^{#1}}}
\setlength{\tabcolsep}{0pt}
\sisetup{table-format=-1.2,table-space-text-post=\sym{***}} % all columns are the same

\caption{ESS regression - Government's responsibility on a scale from 1-10}

\begin{tabular*}{\textwidth}{
  @{\extracolsep{\fill}}
  l
  *{7}{S}
  @{}
}
\toprule
&\splitcell{Job \\ for \\ everyone}
&\splitcell{Health care \\ for the \\ sick}
&\splitcell{Standard of \\ living for \\ the old}
&\splitcell{Standard of \\ living for the \\ unemployed}
&\splitcell{Child care \\ service for \\ working \\ parents}
&\splitcell{Paid leave \\ to care for \\ sick family}
&\splitcell{Index}
\\
\midrule
Age             &     0.00         &     0.00\sym{***}&     0.00\sym{***}&     0.00\sym{***}&    -0.00         &     0.00\sym{***}&     0.00\sym{***}\\
Gender          &     0.21\sym{***}&     0.06\sym{**} &     0.11\sym{***}&     0.10\sym{***}&     0.19\sym{***}&     0.21\sym{***}&     0.07\sym{***}\\
Education       &    -0.10\sym{***}&    -0.01\sym{*}  &    -0.04\sym{***}&    -0.03\sym{***}&    -0.02\sym{*}  &    -0.05\sym{***}&    -0.02\sym{***}\\
Household Income&    -0.11\sym{***}&    -0.01\sym{***}&    -0.03\sym{***}&    -0.07\sym{***}&    -0.03\sym{***}&    -0.04\sym{***}&    -0.02\sym{***}\\
Denmark         &     0.00         &     0.00         &     0.00         &     0.00         &     0.00         &     0.00         &     0.00         \\
Switzerland     &    -0.63\sym{***}&    -1.24\sym{***}&    -1.06\sym{***}&    -0.35\sym{***}&    -1.59\sym{***}&    -2.08\sym{***}&    -0.57\sym{***}\\
Czech Republic  &     0.45\sym{***}&    -0.57\sym{***}&    -0.23\sym{**} &    -0.38\sym{***}&    -0.77\sym{***}&    -0.83\sym{***}&    -0.20\sym{***}\\
Germany         &     0.57\sym{***}&    -0.54\sym{***}&    -0.85\sym{***}&    -0.31\sym{***}&    -0.26\sym{***}&    -0.92\sym{***}&    -0.22\sym{***}\\
Belgium         &     0.94\sym{***}&    -0.83\sym{***}&    -0.38\sym{***}&    -0.45\sym{***}&    -0.76\sym{***}&    -0.82\sym{***}&    -0.22\sym{***}\\
Estonia         &     1.24\sym{***}&    -0.19\sym{**} &     0.40\sym{***}&     0.70\sym{***}&     0.18\sym{*}  &    -0.10         &     0.15\sym{***}\\
Spain           &     2.00\sym{***}&     0.09         &     0.46\sym{***}&     1.03\sym{***}&     0.22\sym{**} &    -0.11         &     0.25\sym{***}\\
Finland         &     0.92\sym{***}&    -0.14\sym{*}  &    -0.03         &     0.76\sym{***}&     0.06         &    -0.88\sym{***}&     0.03         \\
France          &     0.55\sym{***}&    -0.79\sym{***}&    -0.33\sym{***}&    -0.42\sym{***}&    -0.89\sym{***}&    -0.94\sym{***}&    -0.25\sym{***}\\
Britain         &     0.17         &    -0.12         &     0.09         &    -0.74\sym{***}&    -1.09\sym{***}&    -1.11\sym{***}&    -0.22\sym{***}\\
Greece          &     2.19\sym{***}&     0.22\sym{**} &     0.38\sym{***}&     1.66\sym{***}&     0.73\sym{***}&    -0.35\sym{***}&     0.34\sym{***}\\
Croatia         &     2.34\sym{***}&    -0.03         &     0.46\sym{***}&     1.04\sym{***}&    -0.35\sym{***}&    -0.20\sym{*}  &     0.21\sym{***}\\
Hungary         &     2.68\sym{***}&     0.21\sym{**} &     0.44\sym{***}&     0.41\sym{***}&     0.36\sym{***}&     0.13         &     0.30\sym{***}\\
Ireland         &     0.31\sym{**} &    -0.28\sym{***}&     0.02         &     0.02         &    -1.26\sym{***}&    -1.33\sym{***}&    -0.21\sym{***}\\
Italy           &     1.95\sym{***}&     0.16\sym{*}  &     0.47\sym{***}&     0.82\sym{***}&     0.26\sym{**} &    -0.35\sym{***}&     0.23\sym{***}\\
Latvia          &     2.77\sym{***}&     0.35\sym{***}&     0.89\sym{***}&     1.73\sym{***}&     0.62\sym{***}&     0.28\sym{***}&     0.48\sym{***}\\
Netherlands     &    -0.04         &    -0.57\sym{***}&    -0.59\sym{***}&    -0.25\sym{**} &    -1.75\sym{***}&    -1.46\sym{***}&    -0.38\sym{***}\\
Norway          &     0.74\sym{***}&     0.11         &     0.38\sym{***}&     0.83\sym{***}&    -0.06         &     0.04         &     0.14\sym{***}\\
Poland          &     1.84\sym{***}&     0.07         &     0.38\sym{***}&    -0.21\sym{*}  &    -0.75\sym{***}&    -0.39\sym{***}&     0.07\sym{**} \\
Portugal        &     1.44\sym{***}&    -0.15         &     0.41\sym{***}&     0.44\sym{***}&     0.14         &    -0.05         &     0.15\sym{***}\\
Romania         &     1.95\sym{***}&    -0.85\sym{***}&    -0.08         &     1.33\sym{***}&    -0.21\sym{*}  &    -0.67\sym{***}&     0.05         \\
Russia          &     2.49\sym{***}&     0.26\sym{***}&     0.92\sym{***}&     0.48\sym{***}&     0.14         &     0.16\sym{*}  &     0.33\sym{***}\\
Sweden          &     0.32\sym{**} &    -0.22\sym{***}&     0.05         &     0.77\sym{***}&    -0.16         &    -0.38\sym{***}&     0.02         \\
Slovenia        &     1.39\sym{***}&    -0.20\sym{**} &     0.03         &     0.08         &     0.08         &    -0.20\sym{*}  &     0.06\sym{*}  \\
Turkey          &     1.49\sym{***}&    -0.65\sym{***}&    -0.22\sym{**} &     1.14\sym{***}&    -0.63\sym{***}&    -0.17\sym{*}  &     0.02         \\
Ukraine         &     3.24\sym{***}&     0.34\sym{***}&     0.91\sym{***}&     1.40\sym{***}&     0.19         &     0.22\sym{*}  &     0.46\sym{***}\\
\midrule[\heavyrulewidth]
\multicolumn{8}{l}{\footnotesize \sym{*} \(p<0.05\), \sym{**} \(p<0.01\), \sym{***} \(p<0.001\)}\\
\end{tabular*}

\end{table}

\begin{table}[htbp]
\centering
\newcommand{\sym}[1]{\ensuremath{^{#1}}}
\sisetup{table-format=-1.2,table-space-text-post=\sym{***}} % all columns are the same

\caption{ESS regression - Government's responsibility on a scale from 1-10}

%\footnotesize

\begin{tabular}{@{}ll@{}}
\toprule
A: Job for everyone & D: Standard of living for the unemployed \\
B: Health care for the sick & E: Child care service for working parents \\
C: Standard of living for the old & F: Paid leave to care for sick family \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}

\medskip

\setlength{\tabcolsep}{0pt}
%\scriptsize

\begin{tabular*}{\textwidth}{
  @{\extracolsep{\fill}}
  l
  *{7}{S}
  @{}
}
\toprule
& {A} & {B} & {C} & {D} & {E} & {F} & {Index} \\
\midrule
Age             &     0.00         &     0.00\sym{***}&     0.00\sym{***}&     0.00\sym{***}&    -0.00         &     0.00\sym{***}&     0.00\sym{***}\\
Gender          &     0.21\sym{***}&     0.06\sym{**} &     0.11\sym{***}&     0.10\sym{***}&     0.19\sym{***}&     0.21\sym{***}&     0.07\sym{***}\\
Education       &    -0.10\sym{***}&    -0.01\sym{*}  &    -0.04\sym{***}&    -0.03\sym{***}&    -0.02\sym{*}  &    -0.05\sym{***}&    -0.02\sym{***}\\
Household Income&    -0.11\sym{***}&    -0.01\sym{***}&    -0.03\sym{***}&    -0.07\sym{***}&    -0.03\sym{***}&    -0.04\sym{***}&    -0.02\sym{***}\\
Denmark         &     0.00         &     0.00         &     0.00         &     0.00         &     0.00         &     0.00         &     0.00         \\
Switzerland     &    -0.63\sym{***}&    -1.24\sym{***}&    -1.06\sym{***}&    -0.35\sym{***}&    -1.59\sym{***}&    -2.08\sym{***}&    -0.57\sym{***}\\
Czech Republic  &     0.45\sym{***}&    -0.57\sym{***}&    -0.23\sym{**} &    -0.38\sym{***}&    -0.77\sym{***}&    -0.83\sym{***}&    -0.20\sym{***}\\
Germany         &     0.57\sym{***}&    -0.54\sym{***}&    -0.85\sym{***}&    -0.31\sym{***}&    -0.26\sym{***}&    -0.92\sym{***}&    -0.22\sym{***}\\
Belgium         &     0.94\sym{***}&    -0.83\sym{***}&    -0.38\sym{***}&    -0.45\sym{***}&    -0.76\sym{***}&    -0.82\sym{***}&    -0.22\sym{***}\\
Estonia         &     1.24\sym{***}&    -0.19\sym{**} &     0.40\sym{***}&     0.70\sym{***}&     0.18\sym{*}  &    -0.10         &     0.15\sym{***}\\
Spain           &     2.00\sym{***}&     0.09         &     0.46\sym{***}&     1.03\sym{***}&     0.22\sym{**} &    -0.11         &     0.25\sym{***}\\
Finland         &     0.92\sym{***}&    -0.14\sym{*}  &    -0.03         &     0.76\sym{***}&     0.06         &    -0.88\sym{***}&     0.03         \\
France          &     0.55\sym{***}&    -0.79\sym{***}&    -0.33\sym{***}&    -0.42\sym{***}&    -0.89\sym{***}&    -0.94\sym{***}&    -0.25\sym{***}\\
Britain         &     0.17         &    -0.12         &     0.09         &    -0.74\sym{***}&    -1.09\sym{***}&    -1.11\sym{***}&    -0.22\sym{***}\\
Greece          &     2.19\sym{***}&     0.22\sym{**} &     0.38\sym{***}&     1.66\sym{***}&     0.73\sym{***}&    -0.35\sym{***}&     0.34\sym{***}\\
Croatia         &     2.34\sym{***}&    -0.03         &     0.46\sym{***}&     1.04\sym{***}&    -0.35\sym{***}&    -0.20\sym{*}  &     0.21\sym{***}\\
Hungary         &     2.68\sym{***}&     0.21\sym{**} &     0.44\sym{***}&     0.41\sym{***}&     0.36\sym{***}&     0.13         &     0.30\sym{***}\\
Ireland         &     0.31\sym{**} &    -0.28\sym{***}&     0.02         &     0.02         &    -1.26\sym{***}&    -1.33\sym{***}&    -0.21\sym{***}\\
Italy           &     1.95\sym{***}&     0.16\sym{*}  &     0.47\sym{***}&     0.82\sym{***}&     0.26\sym{**} &    -0.35\sym{***}&     0.23\sym{***}\\
Latvia          &     2.77\sym{***}&     0.35\sym{***}&     0.89\sym{***}&     1.73\sym{***}&     0.62\sym{***}&     0.28\sym{***}&     0.48\sym{***}\\
Netherlands     &    -0.04         &    -0.57\sym{***}&    -0.59\sym{***}&    -0.25\sym{**} &    -1.75\sym{***}&    -1.46\sym{***}&    -0.38\sym{***}\\
Norway          &     0.74\sym{***}&     0.11         &     0.38\sym{***}&     0.83\sym{***}&    -0.06         &     0.04         &     0.14\sym{***}\\
Poland          &     1.84\sym{***}&     0.07         &     0.38\sym{***}&    -0.21\sym{*}  &    -0.75\sym{***}&    -0.39\sym{***}&     0.07\sym{**} \\
Portugal        &     1.44\sym{***}&    -0.15         &     0.41\sym{***}&     0.44\sym{***}&     0.14         &    -0.05         &     0.15\sym{***}\\
Romania         &     1.95\sym{***}&    -0.85\sym{***}&    -0.08         &     1.33\sym{***}&    -0.21\sym{*}  &    -0.67\sym{***}&     0.05         \\
Russia          &     2.49\sym{***}&     0.26\sym{***}&     0.92\sym{***}&     0.48\sym{***}&     0.14         &     0.16\sym{*}  &     0.33\sym{***}\\
Sweden          &     0.32\sym{**} &    -0.22\sym{***}&     0.05         &     0.77\sym{***}&    -0.16         &    -0.38\sym{***}&     0.02         \\
Slovenia        &     1.39\sym{***}&    -0.20\sym{**} &     0.03         &     0.08         &     0.08         &    -0.20\sym{*}  &     0.06\sym{*}  \\
Turkey          &     1.49\sym{***}&    -0.65\sym{***}&    -0.22\sym{**} &     1.14\sym{***}&    -0.63\sym{***}&    -0.17\sym{*}  &     0.02         \\
Ukraine         &     3.24\sym{***}&     0.34\sym{***}&     0.91\sym{***}&     1.40\sym{***}&     0.19         &     0.22\sym{*}  &     0.46\sym{***}\\
\midrule[\heavyrulewidth]
\multicolumn{8}{@{}l@{}}{\footnotesize\strut \sym{*} \(p<0.05\), \sym{**} \(p<0.01\), \sym{***} \(p<0.001\)}\\
\end{tabular*}

\end{table}

\end{document}
```

### First table

[image]

### Second table

[image]

Comment: Hello egreg, thank you for your reply!

I'm so impressed with how quickly people respond in here, and how great the answers are. If I could, I would mark your answer with a check mark too. Thank you so much for writing!